# Below SNOWFLAKE query is not returning expected results

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
when Keyword LIKE 'Device announcements' then 'Device stop announcements'
else Keyword  end as Keyword
FROM DBO.PROD_CCMS_RECORDS
LEFT JOIN Keywords ON REGEXP_LIKE(REPLACE(TRIM('* '|| DESCRIPTION ||' *'), CHR(10), ' '),
    '.*[^a-z]' || Keyword || '[^a-z].*', 'i'));
```

The code above searches a column 'Description' for the Keyword 'Device stop announcements'
The description column has the feild -- 'speakers/device stop announcements weren't working, so this driver announced all the stops, including connections and landmarks'

What am I doing wrong/How can i change the query to get the expected results.
Expected result = Keyword = 'Device stop announcements'

Answer (score 1):

You need wildcards in the value you are comparing the column to.

```
Keyword LIKE 'Device announcements'
```

Is the equivalent to

```
Keyword = 'Device announcements'
```

You need something like

```
Keyword LIKE '%Device announcements%'
```

Answer (score 0):

[LIKE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/like.html) anchors the answers as is noted in the [RLIKE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/rlike.html) command:

> The function implicitly anchors a pattern at both ends (i.e. '' automatically becomes '^$', and 'ABC' automatically becomes '^ABC$'). To match any string starting with ABC, the pattern would be 'ABC.*'.

Thus you need to say which end are open to wild matching:

```
select 
    column1 as Keyword 
    ,case
        when Keyword LIKE 'Device announcements' then 'Device stop announcements'
        else Keyword  
    end as your_result
    ,case
        when Keyword LIKE '%Device announcements%' then 'Device stop announcements'
        else Keyword  
    end as fixed_result
FROM values
    ('Device announcements'),
    ('Pre Device announcements'),
    ('Device announcements Post'),
    ('No match');
```

gives:

| KEYWORD | YOUR_RESULT | FIXED_RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Device announcements | Device stop announcements | Device stop announcements |
| Pre Device announcements | Pre Device announcements | Device stop announcements |
| Device announcements Post | Device announcements Post | Device stop announcements |
| No match | No match | No match |